# Check if row exists in DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I have a datatable and a row. I want to import the row to the datatable only if it does not exist in the datatable.

How can i do that?

Comment: Do you have a key in the row (as you should)?

Comment: No i dont have one, isnt there a method like "contains" or "exists"?

Comment: @TamerMemili It has [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hc992ac(v=vs.110).aspx), but that will work only with tables that have PK.

Comment: I guess you will have to compare all values

Comment: yes, i want to compare all values, but i cant find a quick and easy way to do that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use a typed `DataSet`, I.e. declared in design time, the "linq Contains method" takes a typed `DataRow`. The default `IEqualityComparer` will compare all values in the `DataRow`. (Which is normally useless, since you should have a key defined).

```
DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
DataSet1.DataTable1Row row = ds.DataTable1.AddDataTable1Row(bla, bla);
bool exists = ds.DataTable1.Contains(row);
```

Comment: Well, the "LINQ contains method" referred to above is already a method extension. IF your extension was doing something useful it MIGHT have added some value to the by MS implemented extension.

Comment: I'd add.. you must have defined a primary key on the table even if you do not use a typed dataset.

Answer (score 9):

You can use LINQ to check if row is present in datatable. Follow this solution, and replace "id" with your row's primary key, by which you can uniquely identify a row in a table.

```
DataRow dr = null; // assign your DR here
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // assign Datatable instance here.
var k = (from r in dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()  where r["id"].ToString() == dr["id"].ToString() select r).FirstOrDefault();
if(k != null)
{  // Row is present }
```

Answer (score 8):

if you want to check all the `cells` in a `DataRow`, you can try this function:

```
bool ContainDataRowInDataTable(DataTable T,DataRow R)
{
    foreach (DataRow item in T.Rows)
    {
        if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(item.ItemArray, R.ItemArray))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use `Contains` as below

```
if(DataTable.Columns.Contains("RowName"))
{
  //Do some stuffs here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tried all answers here but did not work, so I made something for myself which works in my case. The code is pretty simple, it checks if the row you want to add already exists in the datatable - if it does not exist in the datatable, add it.

```
// fill dt with information
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// create a new row and fill it with information
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

// distinct
bool isDistinct = true;
for (int i=0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  // check if both rows are equal
  if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray, dr.ItemArray))
  {
    // it already exists
    isDistinct = false;
    break;
  }
}

if (isDistinct)
{
  dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( Datatable1.Rows[NumOfRow].ToString().Deleted == "Deleted")
```

Comment: Doesn't address the question

Answer (score 0):

You should check row existence by comparing primary keys:

```
static bool RowExists(DataTable table, DataRow row)
{
    var pk = table.PrimaryKey
                .Select(column => row[column, DataRowVersion.Original])
                .ToArray();

    return table.Rows.Contains(pk);
}
```

Reason is, `DataRow` that you are trying to check against existing `DataTable` is, in real-life scenarios, different class instance compared to the `DataRaw` in the table, even when same `DataRaw` already exists in the `DataTable`. Usual .NET equality-comparison does not work properly in this scenarios. That includes `DataTable.Contains(...)` method.

To properly check for `DataRaw` existence in the table, primary key given `DataRaw` should be searched for in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using any with the key value

If (value.Tables(0).AsEnumerable().Any(Function(x) key = x.Field(Of Integer)("ProductId") ))